# Twitch API and PHP(View Streamer Data)

Tags: php, twitch

I'm trying to find the best way to pull data about users down to display on my site.  In the long run, the usernames will be coming from a MYSQL database, but for now I just created a small array.  For testing purposes, I would love for it to spit out (username from array) and viewer count.  But I'm having no luck.

Here is my code below,  the code below I was just trying to output anything from the two usernames, but it was coming up empty.

```
<?php
$streamstats = array();
$username = array("streamerhouse", "cohhcarnage");

foreach($username as $stream) {
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=' . $stream)); 
$streamstats[] = $stream;
$print_r($streamstats);
}
?>
```

Which I get nothing.  Any advice?

Comment: That did it!  Silly mistakes.  Any idea how I would go about pulling the individual fields from it now?  $streamstats->title;  I would assume, correct?

Comment: In the foreach loop you could add to the array the title instead of the whole data, e.g. replacing: `$streamstats[] = $data;` with `$streamstats[] = $data[0]->title;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 errors. First you have $ before `print_r`. Second one is that you print it in a foreach loop, but you should print everything after the loop. Give a shot code below:

```
$streamstats = array();
$username = array("streamerhouse", "cohhcarnage");

foreach($username as $stream) {
   $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=' . $stream)); 
   $streamstats[] = $data;
}
print_r($streamstats);
```